# when click on the element, ajax request loaded data in first time, after first time prevent ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/php/auth/login.php",
        data: $("#login-form").serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
            //stuffs
        },
        complete: function() {
            $(this).data('requestRunning', false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You haven't shown what event this is running under, but if you only want that event to happen once, use the `one()` method to attach the handler: http://api.jquery.com/one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a flag, check for it and set it to false on complete

```
let shouldAjax = true;

// later
if (shouldAjax) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/php/auth/login.php",
    data: $("#login-form").serialize(),
    success: function(msg) { //stuffs 

    },
    complete: function() {
      $(this).data('requestRunning', false);
      shouldAjax = false;
    }
  });
}
```